# Как достать беседы для чата

Tags: mysql, sql

у меня есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sender_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`receiver_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`message` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
`created_at` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`updated_at` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

`sender_id` и `receiver_id` - это айдишки юзеров - того, кто отправил и кто получил сообщение.

как одним запросом достать уникальные беседы?

что-то типа такого:

```
select distinct sender_id+receiver_id from message where sender_id = 1 or receiver_id = 1;
```

но мне нужно `message.id` получить

Comment: select * from message where sender_id = 1 or receiver_id = 1 group by sender_id+receiver_id order by created_at desc

Comment: блин, но так первые сообщения бесед достает, а мне надо последние

Comment: наконец-то select *, sender_id+receiver_id from (select * from message order by id desc) as message
where sender_id = 1 or receiver_id = 1 
group by sender_id+receiver_id desc
order by created_at desc

Comment: Жуть какая... даже постановка вопроса - и та противоречива (интересно, какой смысл в сложении ИД?), а уж с последующими ремарками так и восе ничего не понять. _наконец-то_ мало того что fullscan, так ещё и лишняя (ибо всё одно её результат игнорируется) сортировка.

Comment: Добавьте две беседы: одну между пользователями 9 и 11 и одну между пользователя 2 и 18. Это раз. Второе - какую именно строку вернёт mysql для данных, по которым нет группировки - фиг его знает. Какую-то любую. А mysql 5.7 из коробки вообще пошлёт с ошибкой за такое.